# Colour Gradient as background colour in textbox for map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, mapping

I'm trying to make a map in QGIS which of course contains the title of the map within a textbox. As background colourscheme for this textbox, I want to use two colors with one color beginning at the far left side of the textbox and then gradually morphing into the other which will be located at the far right. Is this possible in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a rectangle under textbox via `Add Shape`[image]. This rectangle can be styled same way as polygon symbology.

1. Add a rectangle fitting the textbox, style it with gradient fill - set the color ramp and adjust configuration to your needs
2. Move rectangle item *under* the textbox item in item order.

You can also group both item to move/resize them together (select both and hit `Ctrl+G`).

[image]